# Finding coordinates of a vector, using vector methods.

Tags: vectors, quadratics

[image]

My working out:

Vector AB = b - a

let b be = xi + yj

Vector AB = (x + 2)i +(y - 6)j

Vector AC =  c - a

```
      = (1 - (-2))i + (3-6)j

      = 3i - 3j
```

I know to prove vector AB and vector AC are perpendicular to each other, their scalar product has to be zero so I have found
3(x + 2) - 3(y - 6) = 0
How do I continue from here?

can someone please show me a way to solve this problem?

Answers from textbook:

[image]

Comment: Use the given fact that $B$ lies on the curve $y = x^2$.

Comment: Yeah, but i don't know how?

Comment: Simply use the substitution $y = x^2$ in your last equation. In general, if a point $(a, b)$ lies on a curve $y = f(x)$, then you know $b = f(a)$.

Comment: aaaah it was so obvious, thanks a lot VTand